# Embedded Hardware platforms that support Android's FusedLocationProvider

Tags: wifi, android, embedded-systems, gps

**Background**: I want to use Android's FusedLocationProvider to provide location data onboard an indoor/outdoor robot. The FusedLocationProvider leverages GPS, WiFi, Cell Tower, and Bluetooth data to provide location data that is not possible with the hardware GPS-only sensors typically used in robotics, particularly within indoor environments.

**Question**: Other than mounting an actual smartphone inside the robot, what embedded hardware platforms would you recommend for running Android as a Location provider?  I believe FusedLocationProvider requires Google Play Services, which might limit the hardware platform options.